# Understanding the original meaning of face-off in hockey

Tags: etymology, word-usage

[Face-off](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/face-off) means: (ODO)

> - (chiefly North American) A direct confrontation between two people or groups:
>     *last night’s vice presidential face-off*.
> - (Ice Hockey) The start of play, in which the puck is dropped by the referee between two opposing players.

The term comes from  hockey and refers to the action at the beginning of a game as shown  in the picture:

[image]

***[Face-off](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=face-off&allowed_in_frame=0-publisher=Online)***:  (Etymonline)

> - also faceoff, 1893 in sports (hockey, lacrosse, etc.), from verbal phrase in a sports sense, attested from 1867.

Question:

While a confrontation face to face is quite evident from the action described, from which its figurative meaning, what does ***off*** refer to in the original meaning of the sportive context?

Comment: In a comment under @Rathony's answer, I mentioned that the starting positions in hockey are much more like a *stand-off* than in other sports, several of which begin with an *-off* of some sort. Field hockey matches used to begin with a ritual [*bully-off*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bully-off) involving the tapping of sticks; I've just remembered that those single-sided sticks have a 'face'.

Answer (score 1):

Not addressing the *-off* part directly, but *face-off* in hockey comes from its relative, lacrosse. The OED's first citation is from **1889**:

> 1889   *Appletons' Ann. Cycl. for 1885* 520/2   A goal may be scored within a minute's play from the face-off, or it may require half an hour's struggle.

I found several antedatings in 1886, the earliest from **August 1886**.

First, *[Harper's Young People](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=inu.30000093600660;view=1up;seq=700)* (24 August 1886, vol. 7, no. 856, p.684):

> When the ball is started, all the players, with the ex-
>   ception of the goal-keepers, should be paired off all over
>   the ﬁeld, each man close to one of his opponents. If the
>   possession of the ball is disputed by the two players who
>   **“face off,”** let the others approach near them, but not near
>   enough to interfere with their movements. They will
>   each seek to “ tip" the ball with his stick or foot to
>   some friend who has thus approached, and he will have a
>   much better chance of securing it than if he had blindly
>   rushed in and entangled himself in a “scrimmage.” Of
>   course a brilliant dash in between the two players will
>   sometimes secure the ball, but wait until you see the
>   chance. Don’t fight for the ball blindly as if with your
>   eyes shut. Use both eye to see and brain to calculate,
>   and just at the right moment act with all the courage and
>   strength that you have.

Interestingly, the second talks of a proposed rule change to replace the *face-off*.

*[Outing : Sport, Adventure, Travel, Fiction](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015014669165;view=1up;seq=593)* (August 1886, vol .8, no. 5, p.581):

> A new rule has been proposed in the United
>   States Convention, which was received with
>   some favor, and is worthy of consideration. At
>   present, the opening play of a game, from the
>   **"face off"** often results in an undesirable scrim-
>   mage. This is true even when the game is
>   being played by the best Canadian teams. It is
>   a bad impression to give, as a first one, to an
>   audience. By abolishing it, the **" face off"** and
>   all its finesse (for it has something of skill in it),
>   can be retained to be used in case of fowls, etc.,
>   during the game.

Comment: I've sent these antedatings to the OED.

Comment: Interesting findings, from the second extract it appears that "face-off" was used as an idiomatic expression, rather than "off" meaning  "start", or it was just a jocular reference..what do you think?

Comment: I think both are still referring specifically to the start of the game, with much the same meaning as in hockey.

Comment: Another early match is from the _New York Tribune_ of October 3, 1886: "[Boston Gets the Lacrosse Cup](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030214/1886-10-03/ed-1/seq-2/#date1=1836&sort=relevance&date2=1890&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=8&words=face+off&proxdistance=5&state=&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=face+off&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=9)."

Answer (score 0):

"Off" as an adjective has the following meaning in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/off):

> 6.Started on the way.

"We are off to a good start."

In a [*kick-off*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kick-off) of (association) football, it means:

> the opening kick of each half of a game of (association) football.

In a [tee-off](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off) of golf, it means:

> to drive from a tee, to begin, start

"Off" in all 3 examples (ice hockey, soccer, golf) can describe a start in a sense that a puck or balls should be moved *off* its original position in order to initiate the games:

> Two players face each other. Then a referee drops a puck and they start to play in
>   ice hockey.
>   One player kicks a ball and they start to play in
>   football.
>   One player drives a ball from a tee and they start to play
>   in golf.

A [*kick-off*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kickoff_(gridiron_football)) is a method of starting a drive in American football and Canadian football, too.

Comment: So the meaning sounds like, "first we face, then off we go"?

Comment: @Josh61 I would rather say, "First we face, the puck is dropped *off* a referee's hand, then off we go.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is quite the same as *kick-off* and *tee-off* (where no opposing player is close at hand). As the question suggests, I've always thought there was a sense of confrontation as in **stand-off**.  Maybe there's been a merging of terms.

Comment: @JHCL I wanted to include "jump-off" and it also has the same meaning as tee-off, kick-off. The reason they face each other that close has more to do with the size of a puck rather than a confrontational image it invokes. If the puck is as big as a football or a basketball, they would not face each other that close. One more thaing, "where no opposing player is close at hand" doesn't seem to have a relevance as the size of a playing field and rules of each game will determine how they confront each other.

Comment: Well certainly it depends on the rules. In (Association) football, the nearest equivalent to a 'face-off' situation is a [*drop-ball*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropped-ball) restart. No '-off', just the confrontation.

Comment: @JHCL *Drop-ball* doesn't start the game obviously. And you don't use "hand-off" for *handball or volleyball* as they don't need to do that. Generally in *X-off*, off means a start of the game.